# How do I clearly identify the elements of a quotient without the elements of its coset?

Tags: group-theory, notation, terminology

Consider the group of integers mod $7$.  I think of these as the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ but I'm aware these represent larger equivalence classes

Now I'm saying things like "these are all less than $7$.  But skilled, experienced mathematicians keep saying to me things like "That's not true, because $8$ isn't less than $7$.

Then I say "You know what I mean"

Then they say; "You're not getting it, your statement isn't well-defined".

And I say "I *am* getting it.  But when I say they're all less than $8$, there's a sense in which that is true, and that's the sense in which i mean it."

Then they say "if you're not willing to learn I can't help you" and vote to close and delete.

How in general do I avoid this problem by expressly restricting the domain of discourse to the set I intend?

E.g. if I wanted to say "none of these, cubed, equals any of the others".

The best I can think of is:

Let $X=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

Define the map $X\to\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$

Then I think can say unambiguously no element of $X$ is a cube of any other. Is there a better or commonly used way?

Comment: The statement $\forall x \forall y \ x^3 \ne y$ makes sense in $\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$ (or any other ring).  Of course it happens to be false.

Comment: You shouldn't "think of them" as $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. In the "group of integers mod 7" the meaning of "cube" is $x\mapsto x+x+x$. Did you mean "in the ring of integers mod 7"? Even there $\bar{2}^3=\bar{1}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael my point exactly... **I get that!!**  The question is, once I've talked about a modular group; how do I now make plain that I want to talk of its elements without their modular relationship? Because when I try to do so, people think I don't get it!

Comment: Look, you can define a map $\{Andy, Betty, Carl, Doris, Emil, Fanny, George\} \rightarrow \Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$ (actually, many maps) and say that none of those names is the cube of another. But that bears the question, why did you define a map at all, if you don't intend to use the structure of $\Bbb Z/ 7\Bbb Z$ but only the fact that it contains $7$ elements. Your problem is that you want to use some parts of the structure of modular groups, but not others which come with them.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg because I may want a relation that is cyclic of order $7$ but says nothing about the number $8$. I may want to reserve $8$ for something else.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg for example I may want to define an equivalence relation on the dyadic rationals modulo $1$ and restrict to to the interval $[0,1)$ and then I may want to extend the quotient into $[0,2)$ by scaling it by a factor of $2$ rather than by the map $x\to x+1$

Comment: You don't get it and it's frustrating, probably for all of us. Let me ask this way: Do the elements of the set $X$, "as you think of it", have cubes at all? If yes, what are they; if not, why not?

Comment: The elements of the group *are* the equivalence classes, and there's no reason to prefer {0,1,2,3,4,5,6} to {7,8,2,3,4,5,6} or even {14,-6,9,3,53,75,27}. If you'd like to refer to a particular element of each equivalence class, you have to make that explicit.

Comment: How does the statement "1 is a cube of 2" in your last comment not contradict the statement "I think can say unambiguously no element of X is a cube of any other" in your question?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg that was a mistake which I was editing as you replied. I have received a good answer now. What I meant in the question is none of these is a cube of the others in the context of their status as a subset of the integers with ordinary addition despite $1$ being a cube of $2$ group wise.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg although unfortunately I have given a bad example in my question. What I am really striving to avoid is making any implication about other integers not in the set $X$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say something like:

> To each element $u \in \mathbb{Z}/(7)$ there exists one (and only one)
>   element $n \in \mathbb Z$ with $0\le n < 7$ and $u=[n]$.

You can give that uniquely determined integer $n$ a name, like "the canonical representative of $u$" or "the standard representative of $u$" or something.

And then you just have to be careful to distinguish between $u$ and $n$:

- $n$ is an integer in the set $\{0, 1, \dots, 6\}$, and every element of that set is less than $7$; but
- $u$ is an equivalence class of integers.

The "canonical representative" or "standard representative" establishes a one-to-one correspondence between the elements of $\mathbb Z/(7)$ and the elements of the set $\{0, 1, \dots, 6\}$.  But they're not the same thing.

Comment: Thank-you. I think it will be very difficult for that to be misconstrued.